# Pushing into JSON suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner in AngularJS, and I have a problem with pushing into an array inside a JSON. (I hope I'm using the correct terminology)

```
//I have a JSON that looks like this
var items = [
    {name:[
        {names: 'John', msg:[""]}, {names: 'Dolly', msg:[""]}
            ]}
                ];
```

Below code is inside a Controller:

```
$rootScope.items = People.list();
$rootScope.name = "John";

for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.items.name.length;i++)
    {
    if (name== $rootScope.items.name[i].names)
    {   
    People.addcomment(user.comment,i);
    }
    }
```

Below code is in my service called 'People':

```
this.addcomment = function(comment,x) {
items[0].name[x].msg.push(comment);
}

this.list = function () {   
    return items[0];
}
```

The JSON is declared in the service. The HTML code is as below:

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter comment" ng-model="user.comment"></textarea>

<button ng-repeat = "x in items.name" ng-if="name==x.names" 
  ng-click="addcomment(user,name)">Submit</button>
```

Now, my problem is that on clicking the 'Submit' button, the 'message' I have typed in the teaxtarea is not getting stored in the 'msg' array corresponding to "John" (inside of the JSON). What is going wrong?

I had the entire code of the Service inside of the Controller earlier, and the code used to work properly then. I suppose I must have done some mistake with the arguments I'm passing to the function in the service.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: I see your `People` service has a `list` function that returns `items[0]`, but does your service return that `list` function itself?

Comment: OK, I don't understand what you're saying :) How can the service return the function?

Comment: No problem.  In AngularJS, services are required to return objects.  I'll post an example in an answer.

Comment: Just so you know, I have a couple other functions in the service as well, and none of them seem to be giving me a problem. Other than pushing 'comment' into the 'msg' array, I can change value of either of the 'names', I can use splice(), etc. Just this particular thing refuses to work ...

Comment: Interesting, let me look more into it.

Comment: I saw your answer before you deleted it :) Were you implying I had to do like this: return {list:list}   ??

Comment: Would you be able to return an object from the service that references the method names just to see if it works?  I'm not sure why the other methods work in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82697/discussion-between-raphael-rafatpanah-and-anusha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the workflow of you app is as follows:

1. Service is instantiated, JSON is stored in the scope of your service
2. Controller is instantiated, copies the array from People.List() to rootScope.items
3. The ng-repeats repeats for each Element in the rooScope.items - NOT for each Element in the items array in your People-service
4. Someone enters a new message
5. This message is added to items in your service with People.addComment.
6. Step number 5 only changes the items in your service, NOT the items in your rootScope. That's why the ng-repeat doesn't add a new Element.

To keep those two scopes in sync, add a function to your controller:

```
function updateList() {
    $rootScope.items = People.list();
}
```

Call this method after you call People.addComment().

Lastly, maybe this is just an opinion, you should change your JSON-structure. In gets ways clearer if you set up your data like this:

```
var items = [
    {name: 'John', msg:[]}, 
    {name: 'Dolly', msg:[]}
];
```

Now you have an array of objects. Your People.list() function now returns `items` and you can add a new Person by calling `items.push({name: 'Judith', msg:[]});` and you can add a message with `items[i].msg.push("This is a new message");`

Comment: I am actually doing $rootScope.items = People.list(); in my controller the way you've asked me to. I've only put up part of my entire code here :) The comment doesn't get added... Probably I'm doing something wrong elsewhere in my code. No worries, I'll figure it out...

Comment: Don't take your answer down though, it'll probably help someone else who has the same issue :)

Comment: Could you post all of your relevant code pieces? I'd be glad to help you.

Comment: Oh its no problem. I fixed it.. I had put a return inside of the loop and didn't see it . Careless of me :)